# How to enable native threads support in Bigloo Scheme in OS X?

Tags: multithreading, configuration, scheme, bigloo

I am trying to compile `Bigloo` Scheme from source and I cannot figure out how to enable native thread support via `./configure` in OS X 10.5 (Leopard) (and I haven't read anywhere that threading is not supposed to work on this platform).

I run `./configure --enable-sqlite --enable-web --enable-ssl --enable-pthreads --enable-fthreads`, but then in the configuration summary, I am always getting:

```
Release features:
  release number........................ 3.2a
  supported backends.................... native:yes JVM:no .NET:no
  default backend....................... native
  additional APIs....................... fthreads pthreads ssl web sqlite ssl sqlite web multimedia mail calendar pkgcomp pkglib
  native threads support................ no
  openssl support....................... yes (dtls no)
  sqlite support........................ sqltiny + sqlite
  dynamic libraries support............. yes
  bee support........................... partial
```

I want `Bigloo` in order to use `Hop`, and when I try to run it using so created binary I always get the warning:

```
*** WARNING:bigloo:hop
Threads disabled, forcing "nothread" scheduler.
```

Answer (score 0):

The configure script has a switched named "--os-macosx", try with that. Last instance for me would be to go to https://github.com/manuel-serrano/bigloo and file an issue. Bigloo is actively developed as the last release is from May, 2020.